# Professional cash player's salaries

Tags: cash

I'm trying to get a sense of how much money I can make if I decide to be a pro cash player.

And what blinds do they play?

Comment: It really depends. Some "pro's" make nothing while other make up to $500k. I think 10k-100k is realistic depending on bankroll and skill. Only very few people can make more than 50k though.

Comment: What are you making now?

Answer (score 4):

How much money you make depends on how good you are and what stakes/games you play.

There are some players that can make a modest living at the $1/$2 levels of NLHE in Las Vegas. It's possible to play smaller stakes online, but that may require playing multiple tables at the same time to make the same amount of money.

Comment: You'd also need a lifestyle that can handle the variance in yearly income. From what i know, its not uncommon for professionals to be in the red for some years.